# Notes app on MacOS stuck in cycle of high CPU and eventual crash

Tags: macos, icloud, notes.app

My Notes app recently got stuck in a cycle of high CPU (~125%) and eventual crash. Or, more accurately, I should say that my Notes iCloud data recently started crashing the Notes app on multiple machines across multiple OS versions. I don't think it's crashing my iOS app, at least not that I've seen.

I remember the first time Notes crashed and I was doing something I hadn't done before. I had been trying to copy/paste some text from a PDF that turned out to not have character data (meaning I couldn't select text). So I used the selection tool in Preview to outline the text I wanted, and then copy/pasted that selection into Notes. It went in fine, but it was while I worked on this note that the crashes began.

Here's what I've tried, none of which fixed the problem:

- deleting the suspect Note
- went on iCloud and found that note in the 'recently deleted' and deleted that copy
- disconnected Notes from iCloud on a couple Macs and then reconnected.
- disconnected/reconnected Notes from iCloud
- went into `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Notes/Data/Library/Notes/`, deleted the contents of that folder, then added Notes back to iCloud (nothing happened, it didn't sync, forcing me to copy that folder back into place)

None of the above fixed the issue. The logs show plenty of related activity, but nothing that has proved useful. For example, as it cranks on the CPU I see repeated lists of these:

- error: +[ICAttachment entity] Failed to find a unique match for an NSEntityDescription to a managed object subclass
- warning: Multiple NSEntityDescriptions claim the NSManagedObject subclass 'ICAttachment' so +entity is unable to disambiguate.
- warning: 'ICAttachment' (0x600001ef00b0) from NSManagedObjectModel (0x600000aec1e0) claims 'ICAttachment'.

It does this so fast and over and over that it eventually starts cranking out these:

- Detected potentially harmful notification post rate of 240.614 notifications per second

Google's for those and others have turned up nothing.

I presume somehow that Note I created was corrupt (or, the image pastes were), and now it can't clear it out? I'm grasping a bit, but as someone who uses Notes all day every day this is challenging. If you have any ideas, please share.